# nmapi parsing pst files

Tags: c#, .net, mono, pst

is any sample how to parse pst files? official site has nothing

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this](http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=827) is helpful. I don't know about nmapi but CDO was good for mapi.
On the other hand, the **outlook spy** is a good tool to find message formats. Lastly, in the [outlookcode](http://www.outlookcode.com/) you can ask questions, outlook MVPs will help you.